# What's a better way to refer to the methods of the instantiating object?

Tags: php, class, methods, reference, instance

Okay so I've created a simple recreation of the problem I have run into and I have tested the code and it runs. My issue is, **how do call Paper->important() from inside Rock->mb() when an instance of rock is inside an instance of paper without injecting the instantiating object into every method?** I've done it by passing/injecting the $this of mypaper into the methods of rock. The main issue is that only one method of rock requires it, so how can I easily **access the instantiating object's methods without passing them to every function**, considering that I'm running many functions? The last question is, perhaps **does it even matter** that I have injected them into every method, **would it use extra memory** or resources? **Should I pass the $this by reference?**, would it save memory? Also, what happens when I pass extra arguments that aren't used?

```
<?php
class Rock{
    public function ma($args){ //what happens when it gets injected into this function?
        return $args." in ma";
    }
    public function mb($args,$context){ //do I have to inject it?
        if($args=="args2"){
            $context->important();
            return "<br>".$args." in mb";
        }
    }
    //50 other functions that DONT require paper->important()
}

class Paper{

    public function __construct($vitalString){
        $this->vitalString = $vitalString;
    }
    public function all(){
        $list = ['ma'=>'args1','mb'=>'args2'];
        $objRock = new Rock();
        foreach($list as $meth=>$args){
            if(method_exists($objRock,$meth)){
                $response = $objRock->{$meth}($args,$this);
                //can I avoid injecting the instantiating $this, into every function I call if only one needs it?
                echo $response;
            }
        }
    }
    function important(){
        echo "<br>".$this->vitalString;
    }
}

$myPaper = new Paper("Super Duper");

$myPaper->all();
?>
```

Here's the output

> args1 in ma
>   Super Duper
>   args2 in mb

Comment: cool cool... Lots of responses for this one. Perhaps I didn't ask the question in the right place or the right way...

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. The introduction is basically unreadable and the code is a mess. Please rephrase the question; maybe try to explain what you're trying to do and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @lxg dlporter98 managed to answer my question perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do constructor injection instead of method injection as you are currently doing, see below:

```
class Rock{
    private $paper;

    public function __construct($paper){
        $this->paper = $paper;
    }

    public function ma($args){ 
        return $args." in ma";
    }


    public function mb($args){ //do I have to inject it?
        if($args=="args2"){

            $this->paper->important();

            return "<br>".$args." in mb";
        }
    }
    //50 other functions that DONT require paper->important()
}
```

In the mb method I changed your call from

```
$context->important();
```

to

```
$this->paper->important();
```

The paper class now looks like the following:

```
class Paper{

    public function __construct($vitalString){
        $this->vitalString = $vitalString;
    }
    public function all(){
        $list = ['ma'=>'args1','mb'=>'args2'];

        $objRock = new Rock($this); //<-------------------

        foreach($list as $meth=>$args){
            if(method_exists($objRock,$meth)){

                $response = $objRock->{$meth}($args); //<-----------------

                //can I avoid injecting the instantiating $this, into every function I call if only one needs it?
                echo $response;
            }
        }
    }
    function important(){
        echo "<br>".$this->vitalString;
    }
}
```

With the constructor injection you can use the injected class anywhere without having to worry about passing it into each method even when the method does not need it. (Also, it's confusing to have functions with arguments that are never used.) Unless the paper class has a ton of properties holding a astronomical amount of data, you shouldn't have to worry about memory issues.

The constructor injection approach is also handy just in case you decide to add additional methods that require the use of the paper class--it's there if you need it.

By the way, all object are passed by reference automatically--but this is not a concern with the constructor injection approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a wonderful answer. I appreciate the clarity and the time you took. Since I posted the question I had read and tested myself that all objects are always passed by reference, which is interesting. I do not like having to type $this->object->method, but I do agree that constructor injection is the best choice. Thank you again.

Comment: Writing out long object method chains is not uncommon in oop programming. The $this-> object-> method() required here is very common and makes the code readable for those who come behind you.